# How can i cite Sequential Forward Feature Selection (SFFS)?

Tags: machine-learning, references, data-mining, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

I've seen many papers/books about this technique but none cite its author. Is it ok to cite any machine learning theory book that explains it?

Thanks.

Comment: If SFFS is Sequential Forward Floating Selection, as a feature selection algorithm, it was introduced in A. Jain & D. E. Zongker, "Feature Selection: Evaluation, Application, and Small Sample Performance", _IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence_, 19(2):153-158, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3192665_Feature_Selection_Evaluation_Application_and_Small_Sample_Performance

Comment: @Sergio no, i mean Sequential Foward Feature Selection... it's the classic approach, without the floating part.

Comment: If it is the classical approach, then see Ferri,Pudil, Hatel & Kittler, "Comparative study of techniques for large-scale feature selection", _Machine Intelligence and Pattern Recognition_, Volume 16, 1994, Pages 403-413, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444818928500407

Answer (score 0):

do the textbooks have citations of where *they* sourced the method? if not, no one will stop you from citing the best explanation, rather than the originator, of the method, since using third party explanations for sources is common in statistics, given that original sources can either be outdated and illegible, or did not convey the method as an explicit stand-alone technique until someone else in the future reinvented the concept for a wider audience, otherwise meaning that the technique was common sense to many practitioners and maybe even had no sole originator, but many

Comment: I couldn't find any. It is almost like "universal knowledge", none seems to identify its source. However, i'm almost doing what you said and cite a regular machine learning book with a good explanation.